# deserialise the list of integer from json to java using Jackson Object Mapper

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jackson-databind

I have my json response like below:

```
{"IsValid":false,"ModelErrors":null,"ValidationErrors":[10000]}
```

model class:

```
public class ShipmentResponse {
    private boolean isValid;
    private ModelErrors modelErrors;
    private List<Integer> validationErrors = null;
```

Object Mapper code :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
ShipmentResponse shipmentResponse =  mapper.readValue((BufferedInputStream)response.getEntity(), ShipmentResponse.class);
```

i could not able to map the *validationErrors* from json to java ,i.e., validationErrors = null after parsing .Im expecting validationErrors = {1000} but not sure why? i know we can use TypeReference to return array or list but not nested inside data object.

Comment: What do you mean _could not able to_? What happened?

Comment: What are your setters and getters named? Have you annotated them with `@JsonProperty` to match the upper case name of the fields in the JSON?

Comment: Why did you disable `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : i tried JsonProperty annotation, still no luck. I don't have setter but will update the getter in the question shortly.

Comment: @shmosel: as i have more values other than mentioned three parameters may come in the response and i want to ignore them.

Comment: @shmosel As long as it has one property descriptor (get or set), it'll register a property. That property will either be settable through an available setter or an appropriately named field.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    public class ShipmentResponse {

        @JsonProperty("IsValid")
        private boolean isValid;
        @JsonProperty("ModelErrors")
        private ModelErrors modelErrors;
        @JsonProperty("ValidationErrors")
        private List<Integer> validationErrors = null;
}
```

In general you have missmatch in  your property names and actual json (case matters)